# How the onCharacteristicWrite know the status is success in Android ?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, characteristics

I am developing in BLE for Android , I have a question about `onCharacteristicWrite`.

I know the `onCharacteristicWrite` will be call and return the status when write value to remote BLE device.

When the `onCharacteristicWrite` return status is **`0`** after `Gatt.writeCharacteristic`, it means write success.

**Question:**

How the **`onCharacteristicWrite`** know the return status is **`0`** ??
 Does remote BLE device will send ACK to Android ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the BLE device will send successful write acknowledgement. It is part of the low level Bluetooth Low Energy Specification.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it assumes that if no error was received, it was sent successfully. So to answer your question, it *doesn't* know.

The reason I know this is because I have received `GATT_SUCCESS` several times in succession in `onCharacteristicWrite` to a device that was physically powered off and thus, couldn't *possibly* have received the data that was sent.

Comment: The characteristic may have write acknowledgements disabled. So yes, in this case the sender doesn't know and assumes success. But with write acknowledgements enabled the sender is notified about reception and knows whether write was successful or not.